# Javascript array.push changes some elements already in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add to an array, the array at the end should be
> [0] (today) Name:Day1 Date:Fri June 10...

```
> [0] (today) Name:Day1 Date:Fri June 10... 
> [1] (today) Name:Day1+2 Date:Sun June 12... 

> [0] (today) Name:Day1 Date:Fri June 10... 
> [1] (today) Name:Day1+2 Date:Sun June 12...
> [2] (today) Name:Day1+3Date:Mon June 13...
```

[The link with my debug session is:](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v2-HYLab_Yb4RncWa2TfD8iQQrNGdrP8?usp=sharing)

But instead, the Date: changes for each array element, and is the last date to be pushed

```
> [0] Day1 - Fri Jun 10 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

> [0] Day1 - Sun Jun 12 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
> [1] Day1+2 - Sun Jun 12 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

[0] Day1 - Mon Jun 13 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
[1] Day1+2 - Mon Jun 13 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
[2] Day1+3 - Mon Jun 13 2022 10:13:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

If anyone could explain this to me, I would be appreciative. I am fairly new to JS, so please be kind.

```js
// globals
var TodaysDate;
var holidays = [];

function ShowHolidays() {
  console.log(holidays);
  for (let i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    console.log("[" + i + "] " + holidays[i].name + " - " + holidays[i].date);
  }
}

function AJSTEST() {
  TodaysDate = new Date();
  holidays.push({ name: "Day1", date: TodaysDate });
  ShowHolidays();
  debugger;

  var AD = TodaysDate;
  AD.setDate(AD.getDate() + 2);
  debugger;
  holidays.push({ name: "Day1+2", date: AD });
  ShowHolidays();
  AD.setDate(AD.getDate() + 1);
  holidays.push({ name: "Day1+3", date: AD });
  ShowHolidays();
  debugger;
}

AJSTEST();
```

Comment: You're creating multiple references to the same Date object which all get mutated everytime you call `setDate`. You'll need to `var AD = new Date(TodaysDate);`

Comment: That makes sense, I know I'll have this problem again, but hopefully I will remember why. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What you have come across is the age old problem (which isn't really a problem, once you understand it it becomes more of a tool than a hinderance) of pass-by-reference (as opposed to pass-by-value, like you believe should be happening).

To get to the root of it, objects (basically everything you have to use the `new` keyword to create) are stored differently than items like ints, because they are so big. Ints are so small that when you do something like the example below, it doesnt take up a lot of storage so it passes the value of `x` into `y` and now they are separate fields with separate values

```js
let x = 1
let y = x
x += 1
```

However, like I said, `Date` is an object. Because objects can take up a lot of space in storage, they are pass by reference. That means we just pass around the address in memory to all the variables/methods where you would like to use it.

Long story short, what you have created at the end of you method is a long list of 3 references all pointing to the same object, not 3 separate objects. So everytime you do `AD.setDate(AD.getDate() + n);` you are manipulating the object that `AD` points to, and because all the items in your array also point to the same address in memory, they reflect that same change.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I got it fixed in the sample code, now onto my other code. I'm so used to dates being a number.... thanks.